# Where can I download MuleSoft Community Edition?

Tags: mule, esb, mule-studio

Have they got rid of Community edition? I can't find a link to download it anywhere on their site. Is there another link I can download it from somewhere?

Thanks

Comment: Mule Runtime Community Edition is now **Mule Kernel** and is available on https://github.com/mulesoft/mule There is also link to [Installation Guide](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/4.1/mule-standalone).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[This](https://developer.mulesoft.com/download-mule-esb-runtime) is the CE download  site.

Comment: Thank you very much. I managed to also find [this](https://repository.mulesoft.org/nexus/content/repositories/releases/org/mule/distributions/mule-standalone/) in the end as well which you seem to also be able to use.

Answer (score 4):

Yes you can get the community edition, but I found out today in a MuleSoft ESB training session that their Anypoint Studio is available for download for developers.  It just doesn't have all the full features of the Enterprise product, but for developers its a great way to work with the product.

I just downloaded version 3.7. Here is the download link for [Anypoint Studio](https://www.mulesoft.com/lp/dl/studio). The license type and version was:
EMF Common
Version: 2.10.1.v20150123-0348
so it's not a trial version.

They even have some free [online training](http://training.mulesoft.com/).

They are the leader in ESB products, according to the [2015 Gartner Report](https://www.mulesoft.com/press-center/gartner-mq-application-services-governance) and I was very impressed with their training and products.

Answer (score 0):

Agree with James comments..once you download the anypoint studion then you can use the "Install new software" feature and select the different site available over there...on each site you will find both community and enterprise edition though some of the components are available with enterprise edition only...

Are you looking for any particular component in community addition